# Get value from multi-dimensional array using variable

Tags: php, arrays

I want to get keys and values from a multi-dimensional array dynamically, to better explain what I'm trying to achieve please see the code below.

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($faq as $f) {
    $q = 'faq'.$i;
    $a = 'faq'.$i.'_answer';

    echo $faq['faq1'][$i];
    echo $faq['faq1_answer'][$i];

    $i++;

}
```

The literal text above `faq1` and `faq1_answer` needs to be replaced by the variable `$q` and `$a` respectively for me to be able to get the keys and values dynamically, but I cannot figure out how to add the variable.

The keys will always be the same, except for the number, which will change from 1 to 99. So with the code above, I can get the value of `faq1` but I also need to grab the value of `faq2` etc, hence why the variables above would work as I need.

tl;dr `faq1` needs to be able to change to `faq2` on the next iteration, hence the reason for me using `$i`.

Comment: Please try harder to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($faq as $f) {
    $q = 'faq'.$i;
    $a = 'faq'.$i.'_answer';
    echo $f[$a];
    echo $f[$a];
    $i++;
}
```